# How do you get rid of the last empty table row using MS Word Automation

Tags: javascript, ms-word, automation, hta

I need your help,

How do I go about amending the javascript code below such that, I would be able to not have an empty table row at the end of my table that was generated dynamically using the MS Word Automation?

Noted that the recordset that was executed only has (8) records in it.

So somewhere in this code, a row is being auto tacked on?

I've attached a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

The code used below is from my HTA application:

```
function test() {

        var wordApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application")
        var doc = wordApp.Documents.Add()
        var col

        doc.Tables.Add(Range=doc.Range(0, 0), numrows=1, numcolumns=2)
        doc.Tables(1).Borders.Enable = true

        row = 1
        col = 0
        while (!rs.eof) {

            col = col + 1

            alert(row)

            if (col = 1) {
                doc.Tables(1).Cell(row,1).Range.Text = rs.Fields("firstname").value
                col = col + 1
                rs.movenext
            }
            if (col = 2) {
                doc.Tables(1).Rows.Add()
                doc.Tables(1).Cell(row,2).Range.Text = rs.Fields("firstname").value
                col = 1
                rs.movenext
            }

            row++
        }

        wordApp.Visible = true
        wordApp.Activate();
        //wordApp.WindowState = 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
        if (col = 2) {
            doc.Tables(1).Rows.Add()
            doc.Tables(1).Cell(row,2).Range.Text = rs.Fields("firstname").value
            col = 1
            rs.movenext
        }
```

to

```
    if (col = 2) {
        if (rs.AbsolutePosition < rs.RecordCount) {            
            doc.Tables(1).Rows.Add()
        }
        doc.Tables(1).Cell(row,2).Range.Text = rs.Fields("firstname").value
        col = 1
        rs.movenext
    }
```